# sql check that all rows have only certain values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: `Invoices` and `InvoiceDrafts`.

In `Invoices` there is a column called `InvoiceDraftNumber` corresponding to `InvoiceDraftNumber` in the `InvoiceDraft` table.

If invoice used an invoice draft then the invoice draft number will appear in `Invoice` table in column `InvoiceDraftNumber`. If invoice didn't use any invoice draft then null will appear in `Invoice` table in column `InvoiceDraftNumber`. Invoice can be in status sent or rejected. Invoice draft can be used only once , but if invoice that used it was rejected , then invoice draft can be used again. I need to check if invoice draft was already used by checking in this way :

- Take invoice draft number that I need to check ('12345')
- If none of invoices used it (Select form Invoices where InvoiceDraftNumber = '12345') - will give 0 rows , if there are some rows then all selected rows should be in status rejected.

I have a big working query from several selects - select on select , BUT I want something more elegant.

This is what I came up to , but I think there is some problem in my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(Invocies.ID)
FROM InvoiceDrafts DRAFT 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoices INVOICE on DRAFT.InvoiceDraftNumber = INVOICE.InvoiceDraftNumber
WHERE DRAFT.InvoiceDraftNumber = '12345'
  AND (INVOICE.UID is null
       OR INVOICE.Status not like 'Rejection')
GROUP BY Status
```

The count is of rows that are not in status 'Rejection' , meaning if the count is 0 then I can use this invoice draft

Will this query give me the expected result?

Comment: Would another way to phrase this be "At most one `Invoice` entry can be `'Sent'` for any particular `InvoiceDraftNumber` value"?

Comment: No , sorry. The rephrase is 'Either the invociedraftnumber is not in Invoices or if it is in Invoices then all statuses are 'rejection''

Comment: So once a draft has been rejected, it can *never* be successfully used? What's the point of allowing it to be reused if it can never succeed?

Comment: On the contrary , If invoice has been rejected(we are talking about invoice uses invoice draft) then the invoice draft can be used again.Invoice draft can only be used once with one invoice , but if invoice has been rejected then invoice draft is considered not used, since the invoice that used it is no longer valid

Comment: So, at *some* point, the draft will be used again, and if it's successful, do you not then end up with *one* row with a status of `Sent`, and after that point, you don't want the number to be used again?

Comment: I can end up with several rows in status 'rejected' and one row in status sent(the last one). All of them will have the same invoice draft number in column invoicedraftnumber. After this point I can no longer use the invoice drfat 
(unless the last invoice that is currently in status sent will be rejected in some point)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53934/discussion-between-polina-f-and-damien-the-unbeliever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to overthink it. I think you want something like this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM   Invoices
 WHERE  InvoiceDraftNumber = '12345'
 AND    Status <> 'Rejection'
```

If it returns 0 you are OK to create an invoice with that number. If it returns 1, the number has already been used up, if it returns > 1 you have errors in your data.

Comment: Not exactly my case. Either the invociedraftnumber is not in Invoices or if it is in Invoices then all statuses are 'rejection'

Comment: So, I'm not understanding your problem. If the `InvoiceDraftNumber` is not in `Invoices` it will return 0. If the `InvoiceDraftNumber` is in invoices and all status are `'Rejection'` then it will return 0. It will only return 1 if there is already a row with the given `InvoiceDraftNumber` which has a status NOT `'Rejection'`. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I will check this one , I'll vote you up if this is my solution